# How does the Express.js 4 Router let things reach the 404 page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The express generator generates the following code in the `app.js` page:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

However,  in the documentation, it says

```
Since path defaults to "/", middleware mounted without a path will be executed for every request to the app.
```

And gives this example:

```
// this middleware will not allow the request to go beyond it
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

// requests will never reach this route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome');
})
```

So, how could the `404` page ever be reached (or the `/users` route for that matter) if nothing can get passed the `app.use('/', routes)` line?

Comment: In the `routes` file, no `next()` is declared, so again, I would think that it would not "go any further"  However going to `/users` does indeed work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

Let's say your app.js has the above code (straight from the generator) and your server receives a request to `/foo`. First, your `app.use('/', routes);` middleware gets to check if it can handle the request, because it is defined first in your middleware stack. If the `routes` object contains a handler for `/foo`, and that handler calls `res.send()`, then your server is done handling the request, and the rest of your middleware doesn't do anything. However, if the  handler for `/foo` calls `next()` instead of `res.send()`, or if the `routes` object does not contain a handler for `/foo` at all, then we continue going down the list of middleware.

The `app.use('/users', users);` middleware does not execute, since the request is not to `/users` or to `/users/*`.

Finally, the 404 middleware executes last, since it was defined last. Since it was defined with no route, it executes for all requests that get past the first two middleware.

Comment: Great answer. So, as a follow up, how does something reach the `500` error which follows the 404? Thanks.

Comment: Great question. Sadly, I do not have another great answer. I would think that if your sever has an error (syntax error, try to call something that isn't callable, etc), that it would just skip over your other middleware and route handlers, but the 500 error itself is served with another `app.use` statement.

Comment: I think there is something magical in the function signatures? For regular middleware, the handler functions look like `function(req, res,next)` but for error handling middleware, the function looks like `function(err, req, res, next)`. In the above example, the 404 handler calls `next()`, and passes handling to middleware with `function(err, req, res, next)`. I think express is making inferences about your middleware based on the number of arguments in your handlers.

Comment: Also, note that a 404 isn't technically an 'error' until you call `new Error()`, whereas a 500 error is a more immediate error, and would stop other parts of your code from executing